# Pull information from SQL database and getting login errors

Tags: php, sql, database

I am creating a very small, simple CRM for a company, they require the function to be able to view the last 25 orders via the dashboard. The orders are added via a Order-add form within the CRM.
When adding the following code to the CRM I get an error:

ERROR CODE:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user ''rylshiel_order'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home4/rylshieldltd/public_html/sandgcrm/dashboard.php on line 216
Connection failed: Access denied for user ''rylshiel_order'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have checked and rechecked several times and the credentials I am using for the connection are correct I have even given a second user on the database full privileges and tested with this again with the same error code being displayed.

My code is below:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "'rylshiel_order";
$password = "Z]r^0FLF2,NC";
$dbname = "rylshiel_sandg";

// Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT Customername, Material, Quantity, Delivery, TotalCost, Paid FROM Orders";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table class='table table-hover'><tr style='font-size:18px;'><th style='text-align:center;'>Add User</th><th style='text-align:center;'>Edit User</th><th style='text-align:center;'>Remove User</th><th style='text-align:center;'>Unlock All</th><th style='text-align:center;'>View Locked</th><th style='text-align:center;'>File Permissions</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr style='font-size:16px; text-align:center;'><td><input type='checkbox' disabled".$row["Customername"]."></td><td><input type='checkbox' disabled".$row["Material"]."></td><td><input type='checkbox' disabled".$row["Quantity"]."></td><td><input type='checkbox' disabled". ($row["Delivery"] == 'YES' ? " checked" : "")  ."></td><td><input type='checkbox' disabled".["TotalCost"]."></td><td><input type='checkbox' disabled". ($row["Paid"] == 'YES' ? " checked" : "")  ."></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "There are 0 orders in the system";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

As this is an issue with the login details and apparently the password being wrong I have left the credentials in, if there is an error with my code then I will change this.

How can I get the error to go away?

Comment: Does your username *really* start with an apostrophe? `$username = "'rylshiel_order";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `$username = "'rylshiel_order";`
to

```
$username = "rylshiel_order";
```

and you should be through. You are passing on an extra single quote here.

Comment: This has worked thankyou, I didn't notice the additional ' within the username field. I am still getting no data coming through but the error has gone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed that there is a `'` at the beginning of the username ?

If that's ok, then the most probable cause of this error is that you didn't granted access to this specific database to this user.

Check that the user actually has access to the database `rylshiel_sandg`; e.g. run the following query in the MySQL client, when logged in as `'rylshiel_order`:

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```